# Karma Jasmine tests always fails with stacktrace at line 9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a weird problem. Whenever I'm trying to test something and the test fails, it always shows a stacktrace with line number 9.

I'm using AngularJS along with Jasmine and Karma. I found out that it doesn't depend on the browser. An error looks like this:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'new google.maps.LatLng')
    at /Users/user1/project1/test_ctrl.js:9
    at /Users/user1/project1/spec/test_ctrl_spec.js:170
```

So, it tells me that the test fails on line 170 (this is correct), but the cause of the error is inside my `test_ctrl.js` at a complete different line number than number 9. And this line number is shown on every test that fails.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you rethrowing (or is the test harness) the exception or catching it for the first time at that line?

Comment: That's the first time the error occurs, I'm not re-throwing it. Maybe Jasmine does, I'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that with `"karma": "~0.12.16"` and `"karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5"` the problem is fixed. Now I get a proper stack trace.

Comment: With ```"karma": "^0.12.31"``` and ```"karma-jasmine": "^0.2.2"``` this still does not work...

Comment: I have karma 0.13.22 and karma-jasmine 1.1.0 and still have this problem.

Answer (score 14):

This appears to be an issue with using karma-coverage, since the istanbul code coverage tool minifies the source code. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/96) on the karma-coverage repo. If you temporarily disable the coverage reporter in your karma config file, it should work fine.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer: it's because of karma-coverage and not because of the version of karma and karma-jsamine